# Symfony2 Twig Security Policy

Tags: php, security, symfony, templates, twig

We wanted to introduce custom template on our website. Where user have option to create and publish there own templates for there own website (which is using same system).

Q. I wanted to know if twig default configuration is secure enough for **third party implementation**.

but I'm assuming its not. to make it secure we have to use security policy for twig and limit of functions, vars, methods...

Q. I wanted to know how we can change security policy settings for twig in symfony? so all the template for the store template will be security protected.

Answer (score 3):

For your first question: probably not. Twig allows a lot of logic for a templating language/implementation and with that comes quite a lot of opportunities for abuse if you open it up to general use.

As for your second question, you probably want to look into the Twig [Sandbox extension](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/api.html#sandbox-extension) which is provided out of the box with Twig. It allows you quite a degree of control as to what is and isn't allowed and, if you need anything more fine grained, is a good starting point for development.

Comment: is there an tutorial on how to do this in symfony2?

Comment: If there is I'm afraid I don't know of one. A quick google doesn't reveal anything noteworthy so it may be that you have to dig into the code or just tinker until you get the desired result. The answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16070602/4545769) may be of some help.

Comment: Ya I have seen that, before posting here, but does not really help. it would be nice to actually get working example, even if its small one :)